# pandas Find a min value in a specific column in several rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have this dataframe(displayed only a part of it)

```
    name    CEMS    emit    consent
    Ht      CEMS-4  61      50
    Ht      CEMS-5  33.75   50
    Ld      CEMS-1  21.625  100
    Sh      CEMS-3  71.4    100
```

Now, what I have to do is find the mean of emit and then subtract it from consent of a particular CEMS

What I am doing is

```
    mod = df.consent.iloc[0]
    eMean = df['emit'].mean()
    eMean = ("%.2f" % eMean)
    diff1 = eMean - mod
    diff = float(diff1)/float(mod)
```

and I am getting this error

```
    diff1 = eMean - mod
    TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')
```

Help me out in this please

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: You're trying to subtract a float value from a string. Don't do the string casting (`eMean = ("%.2f" % eMean)`) and you should be fine

Comment: Also what is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael As you can see I am trying to do diff = float(diff1)/float(mod) so that I can carry out further operations so I really dont know how to tell you the expected output

Comment: @Abhishek2332 - My solution posted as answer working? Or some error?

Comment: @jezrael yeah it did work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need to remove assign to variable `eMean` in `eMean = ("%.2f" % eMean)` and if necessary cast values to floats:

```
mod = float(df.consent.iloc[0])
eMean = df['emit'].astype(float).mean()
print ("%.2f" % eMean)
diff1 = eMean - mod
diff = diff1 / mod
```